# Изменения отображения точек в мультимаршруте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Можно ли переопределить отображение точек в мультимаршруте? Например, отображать объекты Placemark, вместо стандартных точек с буквами.

Answer (score 0):

Переопределение отображения точек в мультимаршруте делается следующим образом:

```
var route = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
                                    referencePoints: current_point_coords, // массив координат точек
                                    params: {
                                        results: 1, // ограничение на максимальное количество маршрутов, возвращаемое маршрутизатором
                                        avoidTrafficJams: false
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    wayPointIconLayout: 'islands#icon',
                                    wayPointIconColor: '#1E98FF',
                                    wayPointStartIconColor: '#1E98FF',
                                    wayPointEndIconColor: '#1E98FF',
                                    wayPointIconContentLayout: WayPointIconContentLayout
                                }
                            );
```